# Cordova Plugin how to install

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using Ionic and would like to install the following [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/alexdrel/cordova-plugin-icloudkv).

I follow the instructions, and run:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-icloudkv
```

This adds the following entry to my `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-icloudkv" spec="^0.4.1" />
```

So I deploy the code to the xcode iPhone emulator, and:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(cordova.plugins));
```

displays the following:

[image]

**Problem**

As you can see, the `cordova-plugin-icloudkv` is not there.

Also `alert(cordova.plugins.iCloudKV);` is undefined.

**Question**

How do I install the Cordova plugin so I can access it with Ionic?

Thanks

**More info**

My **package.json** contains the following.

```
        "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": {},
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
        "cordova-plugin-icloudkv": {}
```

As you can see `diagnostic` is there and is defined under `cordova.plugins`. Is the reason I cannot access `icloudkv` via `cordova.plugins.icloudkv` is because it is separated by `-`'s?

Ionic Native is accessing the `cordova-plugin-inapppurchase`.

Comment: have you placed this line - "alert(JSON.stringify(cordova.plugins));"  inside ondevice ready event listener??

Comment: Yes, inside: `this.platform.ready().then(() => {`

Comment: are you sure that the plugin is bundled as part of your build? did you did build ios platform again?

Comment: yes, I ran `ionic cordova build ios` and then in Xcode, I start an iPhone emulator to test.

Comment: sorry. I may have to try this out for further suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
declare var iCloudKV: any;


iCloudKV.load(
```

Comment: Glad you cracked it